# How come Indiegogo links shared on G+ link to their page instead of displaying URL?

Tags: google-plus, social-media, semantic-web, social-sharing-buttons

If an Indiegogo link, such as [this one](http://www.indiegogo.com/projects/tiny-homes-for-wis-homeless), gets shared on G+, their G+ page is displayed in the post in the place where commonly the URL would be displayed.

I've tried looking analyzing the HTML, but came up empty handed: there's Twitter cards metadata, there's OpenGraph, there is a G+ button -- but I found nothing that links to Indiegogo's page, not even `rel="publisher"`.

**So, how does Indiegogo achieve this?**

Answer (score 1):

I believe it's a combination of the page having a verified name and URL.

[image]

Comment: Trying to post [New York Times](https://plus.google.com/+nytimes) articles does not result in the same behavior, despite NYT also being verified.